# How can i use "Set-AWSCredentials" within Powershell ISE?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

I am trying to run the cmd within Powershell ISE

```
        Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey <access_key> -SecretKey <secret>
```

But it come back with an error:

```
    Set-AWSCredentials : The term 'Set-AWSCredentials' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.
```

If i try  the command "aws..."

It also comes back with aws : The term 'aws' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.

I have ran the following:

```
  Install-Module -Name AWSPowerShell.NetCore
```

But still no luck.  How can i resolve this and use Set-AWSCredentials and or aws cmd ,  its on a Windows Server 2019 machine ?

Comment: See following especially the NOTE https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-welcome.html